# Number of distinct sites visited by a random walk in one dimension

Tags: probability, random

Is there a paper which explains how the number of sites visited by random walkers on a one dimensional lattice evolves depending of the number of steps ? 
I'm looking for a way to demonstrate that for short time, this number grows linearly

Comment: Why would it grow linearly?  My recollection is that the mean absolute displacement grows like $\sqrt{n}$, which would indicate that, on average, the number of distinct sites visited should grow like $\sqrt{n}$, no?

Comment: Well, for short times and large number of random walkers, it should grow linearly at the beginning. But your statement is interesting, do you have a demonstration ?

Comment: Pretty much any discussion of one dimensional random walks should go over this result.  [This is that first Google result that I came across.](https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/718277.JHizakRLogozar_ADerivationOfMeanAbsDistancIn1DRndmWalk.pdf)